# How to expect an exception in Robotium?

Tags: android, testing, robotium

Here is my test case:

```
public void testStartActivityWithoutExtraData() {
    try {
        getActivity();
        Assert.fail("Should have thrown IllegalStateException");
    } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

The `Activity` under a test throws an `Exception` if it is started without `extras`. So in this test I expect for an `IllegalStateException`, but test always fails because of the issue:

```
Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.IllegalStateException''. Check device logcat for details
Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.IllegalStateException'
```

Logcat is just saying the `Application` thrown an `Exception` which is very expected. So how to handle it in a test? Thank you.

**Update**
Here is the code I'm actually testing:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_item_activity);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            if (bundle != null) {
                EditItemFragment editItemFragment = EditItemFragment.newInstance(bundle.getInt
                        ("id")); 
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.add(R.id.edit_item_activity_frame, editItemFragment).commit();
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException(TAG + " should be invoked with Extras (id for " +
                        "ticket)");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: the code you have should work, can you post in logcat and the rest of the class? I have a feeling that your test is actually failing before running your test (you could verify this with logging) because what you have is the standard way of testing for an expected error. (although you do not need the asserttrue part!)

Comment: @PaulHarris, well, this exception is fired from `onCreate()` method. Might be this can be a clue? I've also added the code to the question description.

Comment: I need the test case class, what i suspect you are doing is initiallizing robotium in your setup with a call to getActivity(). what this will do is cause an illegal state in your setup and not in your test where you are guarding for it or if not in robotium somewhere non guarded is calling this method!

Comment: No, I'm no doing so. `IllegalStateException` is the exception thrown by `onCreate()` of a class which is under a test. My `setUp()` contains the only two rows: `setActivityInitialTouchMode(true);` and `solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation());`
`

Comment: Was there any solution for this? I'm facing the same issue and just created a new question since this is from 2013: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972419/how-to-catch-exceptions-using-activityinstrumentationtestcase2