# How to catch exceptions using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2?

Tags: android, testing, robotium, android-testing

I'm struggling to catch expected exceptions in test cases of my Android app using the class [ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.html).

I wrote a very simple scenario that is raising the issue, and once this is solved I can probably do the same thing for my app. The snippet of the simple scenario is below.

First, there is the application that I want to test, which raises a NullPointerException in its onCreate method.

```
package com.example.crashtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String s = null;
        s.trim(); // NullPointerException raised here!
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
    }

}
```

Then, there is my ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 class that runs this test:

```
package com.my.test;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import com.example.crashtest.MainActivity;

public class MyClassTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity>{

    public MyClassTest() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        //setUp() is run before a test case is started. 
        super.setUp();
        try {
            getActivity(); // This calls MainActivity.onCreate().
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Never gets here =(
        }
    }

    public void test() throws Exception {
    }
}
```

If I remove the call to `s.trim()` then I have no issues, but I want to be able to catch ANY exception that I might find when executing a test.

When I execute the code above I receive the following message:

```
Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation 
run failed due to 'java.lang.NullPointerException''. Check device logcat for details
```

How can I override such behavior?

I have found a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153668/how-to-expect-an-exception-in-robotium) from 2013 which wasn't answered either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test engine (in your case ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2) is like a sandbox. Exception caused by your code will never leave the sandbox via `throw e`;

Error Handling and Error Forwarding is not the task of `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`. Each error will cause that the test is terminated as failed. And you will get some description about the cause:

> Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation  run failed
>   due to 'java.lang.NullPointerException''. Check device logcat for
>   details

So i believe, unfortunately there is no (legal) way to catch an exception throwed by test engine, handle it and resume the test.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
try{
  String s = null;
  s.trim(); // NullPointerException raised here!
}catch(Error err){
  //override your behaviour here
  throw err;
}
```